# Currency Symbol in Dart ISO 4217

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to print the symbols of the currencies in a flutter App, and I am using

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
void main() {
  print(NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'en_US',name: 'JOD').currencySymbol);
}
```

The out put is din instead of JOD, the iso 4217 for Jordanian dinar is JOD and din

if you try the in the playground https://dartpad.dev it will give you din instead of JOD

any idea what should I do?

Comment: there are two things: 1. currency symbol 2. currency name, I test it got currency symbol is `din` currency name is  `JOD`

Comment: And here is my code `var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'en_US',name: 'JOD');
    print("CURRENCY SYMBOL ${format.currencySymbol}");
    print("CURRENCY NAME ${format.currencyName}");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this will not solve my problem, since I want to use the symbols for currencies like USD and EURO, just for currencies without symbol like JOD, it should display JOD. I think the issue is that this library and currency with the name DINAR in it, it will return din as its symbol, like if you used Iraq Dinar (IQD) it will also return din

Comment: yes this is the reason why you get din instead of JOD, but you can use currency name instead of symbol, otherwise find out third party package for this specific problem

Comment: yes this is what I am going to do, I will search for a third party package.